# Getting `Segmentation fault` when running `bundle exec pod` command

Tags: rubygems, bundler

Getting `[BUG] Segmentation fault` when running `bundle exec pod` command. It seems to be from `json-2.1.0` gem. I tried `brew install` but still doesn't work.

```
➜  bundle exec pod --version
/Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
-- Crash Report log information --------------------------------------------
   See Crash Report log file under the one of following:
     * ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * /Library/Logs/CrashReporter
     * ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
     * /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
   the more detail of.

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0028 p:-17569727868076 s:0084 e:000083 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0027 p:---- s:0082 e:000081 CFUNC  :require
c:0026 p:0009 s:0078 e:000077 CLASS  /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:7
c:0025 p:0011 s:0076 e:000075 CLASS  /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:6
c:0024 p:0017 s:0074 e:000073 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json/ext.rb:3 [FINISH]
c:0023 p:---- s:0072 e:000071 CFUNC  :require
c:0022 p:0019 s:0068 e:000067 CLASS  /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:59
c:0021 p:0017 s:0066 e:000065 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/json-2.1.0/lib/json.rb:55 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0064 e:000063 CFUNC  :require
c:0019 p:0066 s:0060 e:000059 CLASS  /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:51
c:0018 p:0011 s:0058 e:000057 CLASS  /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:9
c:0017 p:0025 s:0056 e:000055 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:4 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0023 s:0050 e:000049 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/gh_inspector-1.0.3/lib/gh_inspector.rb:3 [FINISH]
c:0014 p:---- s:0048 e:000047 CFUNC  :require
c:0013 p:0023 s:0044 e:000043 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0012 p:---- s:0042 e:000041 CFUNC  :require
c:0011 p:0007 s:0038 e:000037 TOP    /Users/thongchai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/cocoapods-1.2.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:1 [FINISH]
...
```

The normal `pod` command without brew works. The reason I need to run through `bundle` is the that fastlane somehow requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by these steps...

- run `gem uninstall json`, choose to uninstall all versions
- run `bundle install` again
- now `bundle exec pod` works